# Unexpected $end in my forum script

Tags: php, html, mysql, syntax

So, I'm adding a forum section to my site. So far, everyone thing is good. You can create a topic, view a list of topics, but when you go to view a topic (which is `view_topic.php?id=#`) this keeps appearing:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/papervip/public_html/forums/questions/view_topic.php on line 158
```

So, here's the full script of `view_topic.php` (without the database credentials included, so I can ensure my security :D ):

```
<?php
session_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="forum_questions"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../style/base.css">
    <title>Paperviper - Questions - View Topic</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="games, free, indie, paperviper, pc, video games">
    <meta name="description" content="Paperviper is a game developer group consisten of a team of indie-developers and freelancers. Working to bring you the best cheap and free games for addicting fun on your PC, Mac, and Linux!">
<style type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<?php if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    include("../../header.html");
}else{
    include("../../user/user_header.html");
?>
<div id="page">


<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bordercolor="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong><? echo $rows['topic']; ?></strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><? echo $rows['detail']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>By :</strong> <? echo $rows['name']; ?> <strong>Email : </strong><? echo $rows['email'];?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Date/time : </strong><? echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
    <BR>

<?php

$tbl_name2="forum_questions_answer";
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE question_id='$id'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
  <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>ID</strong></td>
  <td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
  <td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><? echo $rows['a_id']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><? echo $rows['a_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><? echo $rows['a_email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Reply</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><? echo $rows['a_answer']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><? echo $rows['a_datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table><br>

<?php
}

$sql3="SELECT view FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result3);
$view=$rows['view'];

/
if(empty($view)){
$view=1;
$sql4="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(view) VALUES('$view') WHERE id='$id'";
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);
}


$addview=$view+1;
$sql5="update $tbl_name set view='$addview' WHERE id='$id'";
$result5=mysql_query($sql5);
mysql_close();
?>

<BR>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="add_answer.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td width="18%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td width="3%">:</td>
<td width="79%"><input name="a_name" type="text" id="a_name" size="45" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="a_email" type="text" id="a_email" size="45" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><strong>Reply</strong></td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><textarea name="a_answer" cols="38" rows="10" id="a_answer"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $id; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="button"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" class="button"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
<?php include("../../footer.html");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've re-read the entire file about 10 times now, but it still keeps stating the final closing html tag as a unexpected $end. Am I overlooking something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show where is line 158.?

Comment: Line 158 is simply just </html>

Comment: What's this **/** `if(empty($view)){` (notice the slash there)?

Comment: The if(empty($_SESSION['user]')) is used to show a guest header to a guest, and a user header to a user. It works on all the other scripts, so it can't be the problem.

Comment: `unexpected $end` is always a missing closing brace. Learn that one by heart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have an unmatched `{` here:

```
<body>
<?php if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    include("../../header.html");
}else{
    include("../../user/user_header.html");
}  // It looks like this is missing
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I had overlooked it. I feel a bit stupid now, haha. +1 up

Comment: You should be accepting the answer in order to close your question, instead of or in conjunction with your +1 @JakeBrunton

Comment: Sorry, but Stackoverflow doesn't let you accept an answer within 8 minutes. So, I waited until tomorrow. Please keep in mind how this site treats the less-reputation users. :)